# Endless request for input when calling open()

Tags: c++, linux

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
    int fd;
    size_t size;
    char name[]="aaa.fifо";
    umask(0) ;
    if (mknod(name, S_IFIFO | 0666, 0) < 0){  
        printf("Can\'t create FIFO\n");
        _exit(-1);
    }
    if ((fd = open(name, O_WRONLY)) < 0){ 
        printf("Can\'t open FIFO for writing\n");
        _exit(-1);
    }
    char message[60];
    while(true){
        message[0] = 0;
        std::cin.clear();
        std::cin >> message;
        if(!strcmp(message,"exit"))
        {
            printf("Exit to programm\n");
            break;
        }
        size = write(fd, message, 60);
        if (size < strlen(message)) {
            printf("Can\'t write all string to FIFO\n");
            _exit(-1);
        }
    }
    close(fd);
    
    return 0;
}
```

By typing, I realized that the problem arises when calling open ().

When I remove the loop the same trouble Even if cout at the beginning of main write nothing works, but when you remove the lines from open () everything works as it should

Comment: Don't write 60 chars. Write as many chars that you read from the user + 1 for the null terminator. You could also use a `std::string` to read the user input. `std::string message;  while(std::getline(std::cin, message)) { write(fd, message.c_str(), message.size() + 1); }`

Comment: Is there something other than `std::cin` that makes this program C++? The vast majority is plain old C.

Answer (score 0):

> I realized that the problem arises when calling open ().

Some process must open the FIFO for reading, then your `open()` continues.